# How to get jquery autocomplete to display only terms that begin with the typed query

Tags: php, jquery, sql, autocomplete

**Context**

- I am adding autocomplete function to the search engine at [motherpipe.co.uk](https://motherpipe.co.uk).
- I want it to only suggest terms that begin with the letters typed in by the user. For example, if the user types "lon" the function should return ten suggestions that begin with "lon".
- I have about 50,000 terms in a local database
- I have managed to get the autocomplete up and running, working with a separate php script that  calls the database (sql).

**Problem**

My problem is that to begin with the top ten listings in the database (based on id) are shown regardless of what the user is typing in. It is only after the user types a further letter that suggestions appear correctly.

**Question**

How can I modify either jquery or the php code to make sure that ONLY terms that begin with what is typed in are returned (and then only the top ten terms in that subset based on the id.)?

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/autocomplete/autocomplete/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/autocomplete/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("/scripts/autocomplete/autocomplete/autocomplete.php",  {
        selectFirst: false,
        minChars: 2
    });
});
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $q=$_GET['q'];
    $mydata=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
    $mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','languages') or die("Database Error");
    $sql="SELECT searchterms FROM topterms WHERE searchterms LIKE '$mydata%' ORDER by id";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    if($result)
    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['searchterms']."\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I hope everyone asking this type of question, nice style, good context :)

Comment: You can change the PHP code to look at the result and trim out any answers that don't begin with the string passed in and limit to 10 answers. You could also detect the empty string and just return the empty array.

Comment: I don't know why searching for `Shield` finds `Cheap flights`

Comment: The `minChars` attribute specifies the search startlimit to 2 characters. Reducing it to 1 will allow you to search for the first char itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of jQuery autocomplete when you use a URL as a source (like you do):

1. You must return JSON data:

   > String: When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that
   >   string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can
   >   be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP).
2. The GET argument you receive is 'term', not 'q'

   > The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query
   >   string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should
   >   use for filtering the results.
3. The proper way to use real escape with mySQL in PHP is to use it after the connection has been established, in your case:

   ```
   $q = $_GET['term'];
   $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','username','password','languages');
   if (!$mysqli or $mysqli->connect_error) die("Database Error");
   $mydata = $mysqli->real_escape_string($q);
   $sql = "SELECT searchterms FROM topterms WHERE searchterms LIKE '$mydata%' ORDER by id";
   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
   $json = array();
   if ($result and $result->num_rows > 0) {
       while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
          $json[] = $row['searchterms'];
       }
   }
   header('Content-Type: application/json'); // You can skip that because IE doesn't really like it
   echo json_encode($json);
   ```

Comment: P.S. The like statement you have will return the results you need (only items beginning with the entered string).

Comment: Cheers Tsanyo, will do changes, try and report back. Much appreciated.